# PersonQueue is not abstract and does not override abstract method addLast() in Queue

Tags: java, interface

---

I have the following interface:

```
public interface Queue<T>{
    void addLast(T o) throws IllegalStateException;
}
```

Then the following class implementing it:

```
public class PersonQueue implements Queue{
    private Person[] queue = new Person[1000];
    private int curIndex = 0;

    public void addLast(Person person) throws IllegalStateException{
        if(queue.length > curIndex){
            queue[curIndex] = person;
            curIndex++;
        }else{
            throw new IllegalStateException("Queue is already full");
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason this causes the following error:

```
.\PersonQueue.java:1: error: PersonQueue is not abstract and does not 
override abstract method addLast(Object) in Queue
public class PersonQueue implements Queue{
       ^
1 error
```

When replacing my `public void addLast(Person person)` function with an empty `public void addLast(Object o)` function it's working.

I searched for similar errors  but all are caused by a mismatch of the declared interface rules and the implementing class, however I don't see how my implementing class is violating the interface since `T` is a generic for type and `Person` is a type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `PersonQueue` to implement `Queue<Person>`. Otherwise, the compiler doesn't know that the generic type `T` really means `Person` in your context. After this change, the required `addLast` signature would be:

```
public void addLast(Person o) throws IllegalStateException { ... }
```

(which is what you already have).

Comment: Can the downvoter explain why this answer isn't helpful?

Comment: Thanks, this really gave me an insight on what the <> notation actually does and helped me with another problem too.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare Queue interface you use `<T>` which is the generic object type parameter.

Thus when you implement it you need to pass the class as parameter(i.e. `Queue<Person>`) as well like below:

```
public class PersonQueue implements Queue<Person>{
    private Person[] queue = new Person[1000];
    private int curIndex = 0;

    @Override
    public void addLast(Person person) throws IllegalStateException{
        if(queue.length > curIndex){
            queue[curIndex] = person;
            curIndex++;
        }else{
            throw new IllegalStateException("Queue is already full");
        }
    }

}
```